# bootstrap navbar dropdowns not showing with django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add twitter-bootstrap to a django project. I've got a html file called `base.html` which acts as a wrapper file for other html code which is placed inside of it before it gets send back in the `HttpResponse`.

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "{% static '/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% autoescape off %}{{ content }}{% endautoescape %}
</body>
</html>
```

This file is the only file which will ever get send back to the visitor of the webside so I would imagine that if I add the files bootstrap needs inside `base.html` that it would work also on the code in content. Infact, all the css stuff seems to work fine but whenever I try to open a dropdown menu in the navbar of my site, it does not show up.

This is the source code of the page that has difficulties:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="?p=index">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="?p=channel">testchannel</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Username
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="?p=Channel">Visit Channel</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Statistics</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Settings</a>
        </div>
      </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    <h1>A TEST HEADER</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Clicking on the `"/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"` or `"/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"` both redirects me to a file (no 404 error pops up).

what could be the problem causing the navbar to not work? How can I fix it?

EDIT:

As requested the `settings.py` part that handles static:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# some more stuff here like INSTALLED_APPS and TEMPLATES

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/<name>/Desktop/django/myproject/Bootstrap',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have included the correct static path in the `settings.py` file.

I have used something like the following in one of my project and it works fine.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: ahh I will add that part of settings.py to my original question so you can check